# WP_Query title links are not showing

Tags: wordpress

I'm using WP Publications Archive plugins

I want to list Publication attachment to a Custom Template so I wrote below codes.

1st one is showing only the title. But what I want is to linking directly to the publication file

So Under Category ID 13 I need 5 recent file listing with direct download link

```
<?php

// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( 'cat=13&post_type=publication&numberposts=5' );

// The Loop
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
    echo '<li>';
    the_title();
    echo '</li>';
    endwhile;

// Reset Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();


?>
```

Below one is not showing link, Whats wrong?

```
          <?php

            // The Query
            $the_query = new WP_Query( 'cat=13&post_type=publication&numberposts=5' );

            // The Loop

                 while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
                    echo '<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>';        
                 endwhile;

            // Reset Post Data
            wp_reset_postdata();

            ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
    echo '<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>';        
endwhile;
```

You are already in a php block and opening another one. You should be doing something like this

```
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query(...); ?>
<?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>        
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this inside your loop:

```
echo '<a href="' . the_permalink() . '">' . the_title() . '</a>';
```

Comment: Links are ok and title is ok but in my page its showing like this

NO LINKS TO TITLE

http://project.xxx.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-publication-archive/includes/openfile.php?file=http|project.xxx.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/tor_process_monitoring.pdfThis is a demo file (Download Publication)

Answer (score 0):

maybe look stupid but work..try this.. :)

// The Loop

```
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); <br />
    echo `'<div class="box_news">';` <br />
    the_post_thumbnail(array(60,60), array ('class' => 'post_home_img')); <br />
    echo `'<h3 class="post_home_title">';` <br />
    echo `'<a href="';` <br/>
    the_permalink(); <br/>
    echo `'">';` <br/>
    the_title(); <br/>
    echo `'</a>';` <br/>
    echo `'</h3>';` <br/>
    the_excerpt(); <br/>
    echo `'</div>';` <br/>
endwhile;
```